# which browsers are supported by Selenium 2.0

Tags: browser, selenium, selenium-webdriver, versions

So, now I am looking for a list of all the browsers and their versions which are supported by Selenium 2.0

I searched http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp also but it seems the document is not updated, as I cannot see FF later versions like 13 and 14 listed over there.

So far, I have just worked on FF 13, 14 and IE 8

Could someone suggest me any link or a list here the browsers with their versions?

Many thanks for any help!

Regards,

Comment: I don't know about versions, but the latest browsers usually work with selenium (if it doesn't then its only a few versions behind).  Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera, Android, IPhone, and headless (no browser) are all different drivers you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The officially supported browser versions are as follows:

**IE:** Versions 6-10 supported. Version 11 should work fine, but is untested. IE6 support is to be discontinued on 15 April 2014.

**Firefox:** Versions supported using native events are the current version, immediately previous version, current extended support release (ESR) version and immediately previous ESR release, as determined from the date of release of the Selenium components. The last public Selenium release at the time of this writing was on 27 August 2013, and at the time, that means the supported Firefox versions were 23 (current), 22 (previous), 17 (current ESR), and 10 (previous ESR). This is complicated by the fact that this version support is *only* applies to so-called "native events"; if you don't use native events, a much wider range of Firefox versions is supported.

**Chrome:** Version support is determined by the chromedriver exectuable used, and is available [at the chromedriver download site](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), but is usually stated as the current and previous stable channel releases, the current beta channel release, and the current dev channel release, as determined by the date of release of the chromedriver executable.

**Opera:** The OperaDriver supports Opera 12.x. It is theoretically possible to use the chromedriver executable for Opera 15+, but Opera Software has yet to make the necessary changes in Opera to allow this.

Comment: Thank You JimEvans! I have got a sound knowledge on this now. +1 for your descriptive knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

> which browsers are supported by Selenium 2.0.

Mind you, that Selenium 2 relies on on the drivers for each browser.  What you should turn to, is the versions of `IEDriver`, `ChromeDriver`, `FirefoxDriver`, etc.

Each WebDriver supports a range of versions of the browser.

For example, chromedriver 2.2 works on Chrome v27-29 I believe.  As far as a list goes, I think you'll have to dig.  There aren't any sources i've found yet.

Comment: It is quite a shame there is no definitive list actually.

Comment: Open source project. Including the docs. If there's something you dislike about it, "patches welcome."

Comment: We know, and I contribute as much as I can, but i only have enough time! `:D`

Comment: @Sircapsalot: For my code to run FirefoxDriver, IEDriver and ChromeDriver is working fine but I am just curious for knowing them all. I even searched almost everywhere but wasn't satisfied :(

Comment: @JimEvans, we know. Whether it's open source or not, such a list gets outdated quickly. Unless you plan to devote time to keep that list up to date (i.e, keeping tabs on Firefox & Selenium breakages), then any new lists will have the same fate.

Comment: @Arran As I've stated over and over (and over!) again, the project is staffed by unpaid volunteers, most of whom have little enough time on their own too. On one hand, you say, "It is really a shame the dev team doesn't care enough about this." On the other hand, you're also saying, "Fixing it would take too much time and effort on my part for me to care enough to change it." That seems really disingenuous. You can't have it both ways. Either open source is a Good Thing, and you can get involved, or it's not.

Comment: @JimEvans Selenium is great and the stuff you guys do is brilliant. However, you and everyone else (users of your Library included) simply don't have the time to keep the documentation up to date. We all work, just like you do. My comment is more about the continued browser updates make it a daunting task for *any* project. Selenium isn't special on that regard. Open source is great, but many projects fail on documentation. Nothing more than that. It is a *shame*, **NOT** a criticism.

Answer (score 0):

The Firefox driver is native to the main jar as a firefox extension so that's not as obvious but IE and ChromeDriver supported versions can be found on the driver download page.  You can see on the page below that the latest chrome driver supports version 28-31.  One thing you'll probably notice is that every time a new FF version comes out, typically less than a month later a new selenium jar will come out.

https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

ChromeDriver server for win32 (v2.3.220795) supports Chrome v28-31